# facebook pagination next url giving empty set of friend list

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am using following code to get all my friends ,but it gives only 5 friends in data and next pagination link,i have 22 friends but when i click on next pagination gives empty array data

```
    FB.api('/me/friends/?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAIgrQyQs6DaApZAwDCpSub2WHKXaU3inS1QPvcep24avZCoVpyYcHoWgZBltVdFKbKy8UokU6x2JXGEgeDcRu3C3sM2dEZCuzQIsbZALFGPcamyRqR5ZA4VE8c0U2KNcKNar5qVzo9ToAr6BQatoJKd4dIiXg3dqoS4RLlszQjfm3Yf66XxtKxPyIHEDhudQCLgBZCcINLlucERa4ZBf9a8ZD',function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                if (response && !response.error) {
                                    var nextPage = response.paging.next; 
                                    FB.api('v2.1/248176728710033/friends?limit=10&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAIgrQyQs6DaApZAwDCpSub2WHKXaU3inS1QPvcep24avZCoVpyYcHoWgZBltVdFKbKy8UokU6x2JXGEgeDcRu3C3sM2dEZCuzQIsbZALFGPcamyRqR5ZA4VE8c0U2KNcKNar5qVzo9ToAr6BQatoJKd4dIiXg3dqoS4RLlszQjfm3Yf66XxtKxPyIHEDhudQCLgBZCcINLlucERa4ZBf9a8ZD&offset=10&__after_id=enc_AeysBhpBnD6OYeeb4OHHT4qPay7GeUF8OUqNU7PcF3HilkONx4E5EXzymARn2J3u7msA2J4PqjbJyyCE51vHJCOX',function(resp){
                                        console.log(resp);
                                    });

                                }
                                //                                   

                            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get ALL friends anymore, see my answer in this thread: [how to get a list of all user friends (not only who use the app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010519/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-user-friends-not-only-who-use-the-app)

If you still get friends who aren´t using your App, it could be because your App was created before end of April 2014. In that case, it´s a v1.0 App. Your are using `/me/friends` without a version tag in the first call, but with a version tag in the second call. Also, use `/me` instead of that id (248176728710033).

Comment: I am already getting  two user who is not using my App.
After that to see next i am getting  paging link,but it gives an empty set of data

Comment: that can only be a bug, or they ARE using your app.

Comment: btw, you really don´t need to use the access token on your own. that´s one reason to use one of the SDKs: you don´t need to worry about the access token in most cases.

Comment: i´ve added some more information for your specific case

Comment: Hey lunschn ,thank you for replying me.
Please check this one.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v2.1

In GET pass me/friends and it will give all the friends with pagination ,but pagination is not working for me

I am getting here,you can also try.
No they are not using my App

Comment: that´s with the "graph api explorer" app selected. lots of people are using that one, of course you get more users with that app but you still don´t get ALL friends.

Comment: Yeah but even there the next pagination link is giving an empty set of data

Comment: exactly, because there are not more friends using the app. take a look at the additional text in my answer.

Comment: Ok,
luschn ,
Can you please guide me to get the user who is not using my and send them a request ,please ?
I am using javaScript SDK

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/adLidH9Kjgms

Please check this one ,
screenshot of my console response,
and no one is using my App from these list

Comment: check out my answer in that other thread, it´s all in there. see "invitable_friends".